# How can I open emulator or connect LD Player for flutter in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I want to develop flutter apps but I don't have enough RAM in my laptop (just 4 gigs). So, after lots of extensive research on the internet, I installed and setup flutter sdk, android sdk and VS Code. But when I try to run a sample app, I can't see list of any available emulators on my VS Code bottom-left screen.
[VS Code screenshot (see bottom left).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKyQp.jpg)
I am not getting any kind of errors when I run flutter doctor command.
[Flutter doctor outputs in powershell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd6Jh.jpg)
There's a folder in Drive C where I've installed the Android SDK named as "emulator". There's an executable file named emulator.exe as well but opening it does nothing.
[Emulator Folder screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv1Fj.jpg)
I also have an external emulator LD Player installed on my laptop but I am not able to connect it with the code editor i.e., VS Code.

Please refer to the links to see the images as I don't have privileges to upload images. I'm a newbie here and this is my first question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to activate ADB settings in your LD Player Emulator.

First, go to settings
[image: Go to Settings]

Then, select other settings
[image: Other Settings]

After that, make sure that you have activated the ADB connection by selecting Open Connection [image: ADB settings]

Comment: unfortunately this setting gets reset after each time LDPLAYER restarted and should be enabled again, for me open local connection works fine and adb can find the emulator