# How to create a lightweight android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, flutter-test, flutter-debug

My PC lags if I open emulator from android studio ,with chrome and vscode in the background at same time.
So I want to know is there any lightweight emulators for testing flutter apps overlaying in the vscode?

Comment: using an actual device is probably going to be the best you can do, if that isn't an option then you're mostly out of options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [LDPlayer](https://www.ldplayer.net/)
On my PC when Android Studio Emulator starts in around 6 minutes, LDPlayer starts under a minute
I have installed [LDPlayer 4](https://www.ldplayer.net/) and It works without any lag.

You just have to go to **settings>Other Settings and set ADB debugging to Open Local Connection** or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68021232/how-can-i-open-emulator-or-connect-ld-player-for-flutter-in-vs-code) for instructions.

If you are on Windows 11 you can also use [Windows Subsystem For Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/#connect-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-android-for-debugging). It does not have google play apis but other than that it would be the fastest.